# Erasing container that holds a shared pointer also deletes the object that's being pointed to?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

For example, using raw pointer:

```
Object *obPointer = new Object(); //dynamically allocating memory, meaning we have to delete it, ourselves, later

std::unordered_map<std::string, Objects*> objContainer; //container that holds a string key and a pointer to an object type.

objContainer.emplace("A", obPointer); // placing a string and a pointer to an object into the container. simple enough.
```

Now, if we erase that container, it won't free the memory we allocated, the "Object" type. So we have to manually delete it, right?

```
delete obPointer;


objContainer.erase("A");
```

If we hadn't deleted the obPointer, erasing the container wouldn't be enough - we would have a memory leak.
Anyways, when it comes to shared pointers, I don't know if this works, since we don't call delete on them:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> obPointer = std::make_shared<Object>(); //shared pointer

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Object>> container;

container.emplace("A", obPointer);

container.erase("A");
```

Did the smart pointer clean up after itself? Or it will only clean itself when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Unless you have shared ownership, probably want to use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Of course it "clean up after itself". That is exactly what smart pointers are for, in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, like Dave mentioned, I should've used an unique pointer. In my example, by erasing the container, it would not free up the memory allocated with shared_ptr. It would only delete the memory if it ran out of scope or references.
Therefore, as Dave suggested, I used an unique_pointer to created the memory, then I "passed" it to the container using "std::move," which transfers ownership TO the container's pointer. Therefore, the memory will free as soon as I erase that container. Like so:

```
//Container
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Object>> //container;
{//Scope just to demonstrate it works
 std::unique_ptr<Object> obPointer = std::make_unique<Object>(); //unique pointer

/*Now we transfer the ownership to the container, making its life spam
rely on the scope of the CONTAINER and the container itself*/
container.emplace("A", std::move(obPointer)); //std::move very important

}//only "obPointer" will die cuz of the scope, but it's null now. 
// the actual object that we created didn't delete itself. It's in the container



/*If we want to free up the memory, we should just erase the specific container
or wait for it to be out of the scope.*/
 container.erase("A"); //pointer deleted and memory freed
```

There you go. A way to "manually" delete a smart pointer. Very useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Whatever happens last**

Since you have a shared pointer, it keeps track of how many copies of it exist. In your case, there is `obPointer` in your local scope and one object inside `container` (so 2 in total).
After the call to `erase`, the object in `container` gets destructed and the count goes back to 1. When `obPointer` goes out of scope, the count goes to 0 and the `QObject` instance gets deleted.

Comment: So, the object will be just standing there in memory until it gets out of scope? That kinda sucks. Is there a way to delete it? If not, I prefer to use raw pointers in this case.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. But in general, you should trust the compiler optimizer instead of trying to manually optimize for something you haven't identified to be a problem. Also if you only want the object in the container, why are you using a shared pointer instead of a unique pointer?

Comment: I thought I couldn't pass unique pointers around? I can't place a unique pointer in the container, can I?

Comment: You can't copy unique pointers. If you construct the pointer in the container (via emplace) it works, because then it is only in one place. You can also not use dynamic allocation at all and just store the plain `QObjects` in there.